# Is there a way to automatically pull a list of YouTube video viewcounts into a Google Doc spreadsheet?

Tags: youtube, google-sheets

I want to create a simple video dashboard for some of my teaching videos, to see what's trending etc.

Is there a way to pull video counts from your channel, directly (preferably programmatically) into a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: So, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: YouTube launched YouTube dashboard this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from Web Applications:

Please try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6RsJmelphk","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

which should return something like 97,000 (views for a Colin Farrell - Road to Hell video).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you can try and use [Google App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). I am sure Youtube has a HTTP REST API that you can query to pull the necessary information into a Google Doc.

There is a little coding involved here, but its a just an Idea that might work.

Update : [Tutorial on Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_writing_scripts)

Hope this helps, Cheers!